How can you control the vertical space before and after an equation (on its own line) in a figure caption?
I want to insert an equation (on its own line) in a figure caption.
The default spacing before and after the equation in the caption looks too big to me. How can I adjust the spacing before and after the equation in the figure  to be smaller?
I tried wrapping the equation in a minipage, but this got rid of the vertical spacing entirely, and it was not clear to me how to independently add equal vertical spaces before and after the equation when it was wrapped in a minipage.
Here is small example of my setup:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{boxed}{%
  \kern0.05em{\color[rgb]{0.99,0.78,0.07}\rule{0.63em}{0.63em}}%
  \hspace*{0.62em}\bothIfFirst{#1}{~}#2}
\captionsetup{labelformat=boxed}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption[]{
I write for a bit \dots \lipsum[1] and then have an equation
% I want to insert some command here to control the vertical space BEFORE the equation
% \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \[\xi(\mathcal{P}) = (x_1y_1 + x_2y_2)(y_1z_1 + y_2z_2)\]
        % \end{minipage} 
% I want to insert some command here to control the vertical space AFTER the equation
on its own line. 
Is the equation spacing alright? 
}
\label{fig:some-label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}


You can probably set \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip locally in the caption.

Yup, changes are local to the caption.  Note that displayed equations are implemented using a trivlist, and \belowdisplayskip needs to be set before (not after)..
